# Unable to select a certain row in a C# WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

As stated I have a datagrid I NC# WPF that is populated with 13 rows of information. When clicking on a row I can select the row and the SelectionChanged event fires except for row #10. Clicking on this row won't even select the row. If I click on the row above or below it, the event fires, and I can then use the keyboard up or down arrows to navigate to row #10 and select it, and have the event fire, just not from a mouse click, and only this one row.

There is nothing about row that is different then the others, and is 100% repeatable. So why can't I select this one row with a mouse click? What should I be checking?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" Width="826" Height="320" Margin="18,45,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding}" CanUserResizeColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" SelectionChanged="dgBatches_SelectionChanged">  
<DataGrid.Columns>  
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit" Width="*" MinWidth="150" DisplayIndex="0" Binding="{Binding Path=Unit_Desc}" />  
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Current Phase" Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" DisplayIndex="1" Binding="{Binding Path=Status_Phase}" />  
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Batch" Width="Auto" MinWidth="80" DisplayIndex="2" Binding="{Binding Path=Batch_Number}" />  
</DataGrid.Columns>  
</DataGrid>  

private void MyDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)  
{  
int selectedIndex = MyDataGrid.SelectedIndex;  
}  

private void PopulateMyDataGrid()
{
StoredProcedureExecutionResult sper = null;
List<Parameter> parameterList = new List<Parameter>();
parameterList.Add(CreateServiceParameter(1, "@ProductionDay", "9/15/2013");
sper = _databaseService.ExecuteProcedure(_databaseConnectionDor, "sp_PopulateGrid", parameterList);
if (null != sper.FirstTable)
{
    DataTable batchTable = sper.FirstTable.DataTable.Copy();
    MyDataGrid.DataContext = null;
    MyDataGrid.DataContext = batchTable;
    MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Dude, post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: Post the code where you are creating rows. And include the Data Item.

Comment: Row creation is bound to a stored procedure that returns 13 rows, I'll post what I am doing there too

Comment: Why are you setting `DataContext` instead of `ItemsSource`?

Comment: Beats me, I was handed the code base and that is what they were doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it working. IN Visual Studio I right-clicked on the grid, went to Options, and selected Bring to Front. After doing that I was able to click on any row in the grid in select it. Why? I have no idea.